# Ansible: No package matching 'nginx' is available

Tags: nginx, ansible

I have an Ansible playbook which worked on a different machine.

But here it fails:

> ```
> fatal: [coffee-and-sugar.club]: FAILED! => 
> {"changed": false, "msg": "No > package matching 'nginx' is available"}
> ```

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: ensure nginx is at the latest version
      apt: name=nginx state=latest
    - name: start nginx
      service:
          name: nginx
          state: started
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

guettli's answer is correct but you can also make it shorter, calling the apt module only once:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Update and upgrade apt packages
      apt:
        name: nginx
        state: latest
        update_cache: yes
        upgrade: yes
    - name: start nginx
      service:
          name: nginx
          state: started
```

Answer (score 2):

If the machine was setup up just some seconds ago, then you need to run `apt update` at least once.

You can do it like this via Ansible:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Update and upgrade apt packages
      apt:
        update_cache: yes
        upgrade: yes
    - name: ensure nginx is at the latest version
      apt: name=nginx state=latest
    - name: start nginx
      service:
          name: nginx
          state: started
```